# Angular 2 Pipe inside Primeng Datatable gives security error

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a Pipe which decodes the html codes. For example `<p>test</p>` becomes `test`

When I use it inside a column, it doesn't show the data but '`SafeValue must use [property]=binding: XXXX (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`'

**Datatable**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="toShowSubVragen">

   <!-- WITH Pipe, DOESN'T WORK
   SHOWS: SafeValue must use [property]=binding: XXXX (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)-->
    <p-column field="tekst" header="With Pipe">
        <template let-col let-vraag="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <span>{{vraag[col.field] | safeHtml}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>

    <!-- WITHOUT Pipe, WORKS
   SHOWS: the tekst data..  -->
    <p-column field="tekst" header="Without Pipe">
        <template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <span>{{car[col.field]}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

**Pipe**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer `SafeValue` It doesn't come from my data. I guess from the pipe's classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `safeHtml` or the sanitizer directly with `{{}}` is pointless because the result is stringified which undoes the application of `| safeHtml`.

```ts
<span>{{vraag[col.field] | safeHtml}}</span>
```

Perhaps you meant

```ts
<span [innerHTML]="vraag[col.field] | safeHtml"></span>
```

Comment: that's exactly where I was wrong. thank you! changed the line `<span>{{vraag[col.field] | safeHtml}}</span>` to `<span [innerHTML]="vraag[col.field] | safeHtml"></span>`